# I need page-numbering odd-roman

Tags: numbering, page-numbering, roman

I'm trying to number the pages with only odd number.
how to change the count from **(1,2,3,4,5)** to **(1,3,5,7,9)** in latex?

Answer (score 5):

The page counter still counts 1, 2, 3, ..., but `\thepage` is redefined to use 2*page-1 instead. Also `\@roman` is used to get roman numbers. The calculation is done using e-TeX's `\numexpr`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{%
  \@roman{\numexpr\value{page}*2-1\relax}%
}
\makeatother
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{%
  \@roman{\numexpr\value{page}*2-1\relax}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\null\newpage
\null\newpage
\null\newpage
\end{document}
```

Result is three empty pages with `i`, `iii`, `v` as page number in the footer.