# Multiple page list of figures with non sequential numbering

Tags: numbering, fancyhdr

Any suggestions on how to automatically make the list of figures exhibit page numbers in non sequential fashion, with a step between each number, as for example:

- first page of lof: page number => **xi**
- second page of lof: page number => **xiii**
- third page of lof: page number => **xv**

I'm using fancyhdr to handle pagestyle. All my *\frontmatter* pages should be in **roman**, but odd counting (i,iii,v,...), while *\mainmatter* should return to **arabic**, in sequence, like (10,11,...). And I'd like to have only the page numbers in  cfoot through all the documents (no chapters/section names and foot or head rule)

Here a mwe:

```
\documentclass[
% -- opções da classe memoir --
12pt,               % tamanho da fonte
openright,          % capítulos começam em pág ímpar (insere página vazia caso preciso)
oneside,            % para impressão em recto e verso. Oposto a oneside
a4paper,            % tamanho do papel. 
% -- opções da classe abntex2 --
chapter=TITLE,      % títulos de capítulos convertidos em letras maiúsculas
section=TITLE,      % títulos de seções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
subsection=TITLE,   % títulos de subseções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
subsubsection=TITLE,% títulos de subsubseções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
% -- opções do pacote babel --
english,            % idioma adicional para hifenização
%french,                % idioma adicional para hifenização
%spanish,           % idioma adicional para hifenização
brazil,             % o último idioma é o principal do documento
]{abntex2}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[OEC]{\thepage}
}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\pagestyle{mystyle}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}          % 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}          % 
\headheight 14.5pt      

\makeatletter

\listoffigures
%\selectlanguage{brazil}
\frenchspacing 
\mainmatter

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\sloppy
\foreach \x in {1,...,40} {%
\chapter{Foo \x}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{Foo figure \x}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{Foo other figure \x}
\end{figure}
}
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: what is the purpose? but beside this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/264604/2388

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369219/random-page-numbers?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C105.9694